# Prevent MS Word from breaking paragraphs across pages

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I'd like to stop MS Word from breaking paragraphs across page breaks.

I know I can do this for individual paragraphs by selecting them and setting "Keep Lines Together" in the paragraph settings, but how can I make this happen for all paragraphs?

I have tried selecting "Make Default" for this document but it doesn't seem to have any effect at all, not even on the currently selected paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to modify the "Normal" or "Default" style. You can open the Styles menu by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (so I'm told). After doing so, you might need to apply the update to the pre-existing text.

Comment: +1 for that nasty but useful four-keystrokes keyboard shortcut.

Comment: for anyone else with same problem: once the styles menu is open, select the manage styles button, then select the relevant style (normal here) and click modify. Then select format->Paragraph.